# Sharp network scanner tool?

Tags: networking, scanner

I could not find anything about sharp network scanner tool. Is there any way my sharp machine scanner work with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

you probably need `nmap`

```
  Nmap (“Network Mapper”) is an open source tool for network exploration
       and security auditing. It was designed to rapidly scan large networks,
       although it works fine against single hosts. Nmap uses raw IP packets
       in novel ways to determine what hosts are available on the network,
       what services (application name and version) those hosts are offering,
       what operating systems (and OS versions) they are running, what type of
       packet filters/firewalls are in use, and dozens of other
       characteristics. While Nmap is commonly used for security audits, many
       systems and network administrators find it useful for routine tasks
       such as network inventory, managing service upgrade schedules, and
       monitoring host or service uptime.
```

check the [manpage for the `nmap` command [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/nmap.1)

Here a list of network tools that could you be interested in:

1) Wireshark -- network traffic analyzer

2) Nessus -- Remote network security auditor

3) Nmap -- The Network Mapper

4) Etherape -- graphical network monitor modeled after etherman

5) Kismet -- Wireless 802.11b monitoring tool

6) Chkrootkit -- Checks for signs of rootkits on the local system

7) Rkhunter -- rootkit, backdoor, sniffer and exploit scanner

8) tiger -- Report system security vulnerabilities

and much more security tools [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/list-of-security-tools-available-in-ubuntu.html)

Comment: He obviously means he needs support for an image scanner connected via the network, like a Multi-Function Printer (MFP). This has nothing to do with network scanning in the "nmap" sense.